# What are all the contents I can add to a Discord webhook?

Tags: discord, discord.js, webhooks

I am making a discord webhook, and I want to know all the different things I can add to it.

As far as styling it goes; I only have a color and a message. (My code is not included besides that, just the code for the color and the message)

```
    .setTitle('Biscuit AIO Cooked!')
    .setColor('#84e1f4');
```

If anyone can link me a site or reply to me with all of the things I can add to the webhook, please do so :)

Comment: That's a discord embed not a webhook. If you want docs on 'things you can add' then its best to just go to the official docs: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/

Comment: No, It is a webhook. I got this to send a webhook to my discord.

Comment: You can send embeds on messages with webhooks. setColor and setTitle are called on embeds not webhooks.

Comment: well I got that code from discord's webhook guide

Answer (score 1):

Read about [message embeds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/class/MessageEmbed) and [embed visualizer](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/).
At last one of the features of a webhook is that you can send several embeds at once message. So code will looks like this.

````
{
  "content": "this `supports` __a__ **subset** *of* ~~markdown~~  ```js\nfunction foo(bar) {\n  console.log(bar);\n}\n\nfoo(1);```",
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "title ~~(did you know you can have markdown here too?)~~",
      "description": "this supports [named links](https://discordapp.com) on top of the previously shown subset of markdown. ```\nyes, even code blocks```",
      "url": "https://discordapp.com",
      "color": 11038012,
      "timestamp": "2020-07-03T15:05:41.392Z",
      "footer": {
        "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
        "text": "footer text"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "image": {
        "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "author": {
        "name": "author name",
        "url": "https://discordapp.com",
        "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "some of these properties have certain limits..."
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "try exceeding some of them!"
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "an informative error should show up, and this view will remain as-is until all issues are fixed"
        },
        {
          "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
          "value": "these last two",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
          "value": "are inline fields",
          "inline": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "title ~~(did you know you can have markdown here too?)~~",
      "description": "this supports [named links](https://discordapp.com) on top of the previously shown subset of markdown. ```\nyes, even code blocks```",
      "url": "https://discordapp.com",
      "color": 11038012,
      "timestamp": "2020-07-03T15:05:41.392Z",
      "footer": {
        "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png",
        "text": "footer text"
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "image": {
        "url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "author": {
        "name": "author name",
        "url": "https://discordapp.com",
        "icon_url": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/0.png"
      },
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "some of these properties have certain limits..."
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "try exceeding some of them!"
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "value": "an informative error should show up, and this view will remain as-is until all issues are fixed"
        },
        {
          "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
          "value": "these last two",
          "inline": true
        },
        {
          "name": "<:thonkang:219069250692841473>",
          "value": "are inline fields",
          "inline": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
````